# How do i check if an input matches a specific letter?

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to check whether the input is a specific letter. I know how to check if it's a specific `int`/`double` but when it's a `string` I don't know what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just trying to make a basic 3 question quiz that checks whether the user answers with the correct letter (a, b or c) and then adds that to the current score.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a1 = "a";
        var a2 = "b";
        var a3 = "c";
        var qa = 0;
        while (qa != 3)
        {
            if (qa == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("What is the answer to question 1? ");
                var entry1 = Console.Read();

                if()
                {

                }                                              
            }

            else if (qa == 1)
            {
                Console.Write("What is the answer to question 2? ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else if (qa == 2)
            {
                Console.Write("What is the answer to question 3? ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }                
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to increase the `qa` to get to the other questions

Comment: Why use a while loop, when you're not using arrays. You could write those statements serial. (without if's etc)

Comment: I agree with @JeroenvanLangen - the `while` loop isn't really necessary here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS it only makes it more complex. just... KISS ;-)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Okay thank you, i will keep that in mind next time. Now you say it does indeed not make much sense, but for some reason when writing it it made sense in my head :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example operator == can't be applied to strings

this is not true. It can be applied:

```
if(entry.ToString() == a1)
```

The [documentation for the `==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) tells us:

> For the string type, == compares the values of the strings

another possibility would be to use the [String.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
if(entry.ToString().Equals(a1))
```

**EDIT:**

Looking closer at your code I realized that you are using [Console.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx)
 which

> Reads the next character from the standard input stream.

That means that it returns a `char` (and only 1).

I guess you want the entire line that the user types in. So you should use [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. It returns a `string` and allows you for a direct comparison

```
string entry1 = Console.ReadLine();
if(entry == a1)
```

when you use `var` for the declaration of types the compiler infers the type and the error becomes obvious at a later stage. you cannot use the `==` operator on `string` and `char` . `Read()` returns a `char` so that's why you were not able to compare it in the first place

Comment: Superb point about the `==` operator, nice documentation link too

Comment: Huh... apparently I always missed the part in the doc about it not using reference comparison for strings.. I've always just used `Equals()` to be safe..

Comment: Holy shit, thanks for the fast response! I got it to work now, that Strings.Equals was exactly the type of method i was looking for. And my bad for saying it can't be applied to strings, i was using it wrong.

Comment: @JesseSchoonveld no you were not using it wrong. when you use `var` for the declaration of types the compiler infers the type and the error becomes obvious at a later stage. you cannot use it on `string` and `char` . Read() returns a `char` so that's why you were not able to compare it in the first place

Comment: @MongZhu Yea i did :) I'm doing an extra assignment on Teamtreehouse.com and this one thing was what made everything super confusing to me. But thanks to your answer and some more clarification by other users i think i understand the material now.

Comment: @JesseSchoonveld glad I could help. Have fun learning C#. I sure have :) It is a great language.

Comment: For some reason this question got downvoted and now i cannot ask any more questions for 4 days...but i have no idea what i did that got it downvoted. Do you have any suggestions as to how i can avoid this in the future?

Comment: @JesseSchoonveld you should have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Preferably read the entire **asking** section in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). First of all, it is expected here that the people show some research effort. Second post the minimum and maximum amount of code to reproduce the problem. Don't expect the people to write code for you. But I have to admit, that it is not that easy to post a question in the beginning, which will not get downvoted ;) good luck next time

Answer (score 1):

Note that in "Question 1" you wrote Console.Read(), (not Console.ReadLine()) which returns a char, not a string. So  "==" cannot be applied to entry1 and a1 since entry1 will be a char while a1 is a string.

Comment: good point with the `Read` Method. easy to overlook when elsewhere OP uses `ReadLine`

Comment: Thank you, i was a bit confused about how ReadLine worked compared to Read and you explained it.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare compatible variables, everything should be fine

```
string input1;
var input2 = "";
var input3 = 0;

// assign some input values, then compare

// strings
if (input1 == "a") // ok
{ }
if (input2 == "a") // ok
{ }
if (input3 == "a") // not ok, comparing int to string
{ }
// numbers
if (input1 == 1) // not ok, comparing string to int
{ }
if (input3 == 1) // ok
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, you could try matching the ASCII value of the character by using Console.Read();. This would eliminate the need to press enter. If you were trying to match to uppercase A:

```
    int input = Console.Read();
    if (input == (int)char.GetNumericValue(A))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
        Console.Read();

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
        Console.Read();

    }
```